# Stop logging Gatling Requests

Tags: maven, logging, gatling

I'm monitoring many web pages (around 4000), whose URLs are fed by a CSV file in the same Gatling test.

The problem is the test lasts forever. I suppose (but it may not be true) that the logging activity takes a long time. So I want to stop having the huge table with

```
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Whatever
> Blah blah blah
> And so on
---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
> You got it
```

... only to see if it makes my test last a bit shorter.

How should I do?

I tried editing my `logback-test.xml` file but the logs show even with the ERROR level.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %logger{15} - %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
            <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Uncomment for logging ALL HTTP request and responses -->
    <!--    <logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="TRACE" /> -->
    <!--    <logger name="io.gatling.http.response" level="TRACE" /> -->
    <!-- Uncomment for logging ONLY FAILED HTTP request and responses -->
    <!--    <logger name="io.gatling.http.ahc" level="DEBUG" /> -->
    <!--    <logger name="io.gatling.http.response" level="DEBUG" /> -->

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Also, for all purposes, here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dead_url_spotter</groupId>
    <artifactId>dead_url_spotter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <scala.version>2.11.7</scala.version>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

        <gatling.version>2.2.3</gatling.version>

        <scala-maven-plugin.version>3.2.2</scala-maven-plugin.version>
        <gatling.maven.version>2.2.1</gatling.maven.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-app</artifactId>
                <version>${gatling.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-recorder</artifactId>
                <version>${gatling.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
                <version>${gatling.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                <version>${scala.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.typesafe.scala-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-logging_2.12</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-app</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-recorder</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.json</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cedarsoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-io</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmxtrans</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxtrans</artifactId>
            <version>263</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArgs>
                        <jvmArg>-Durl=http://localhost:9000</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-DnumberOfUsers=10</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-DnumberOfRepetitions=1</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-DdurationMinutes=1</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-DpauseBetweenRequestsMs=3000</jvmArg>
                        <jvmArg>-Ddebug=false</jvmArg>
                    </jvmArgs>
                    <configFolder>src/test/resources</configFolder>
                    <dataFolder>src/test/resources/data</dataFolder>
                    <resultsFolder>target/gatling/results</resultsFolder>
                    <bf>src/test/resources/bodies</bf>
                    <simulationsFolder>src/test/scala</simulationsFolder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-Ybackend:GenBCode</arg>
                                <arg>-Ydelambdafy:method</arg>
                                <arg>-target:jvm-1.8</arg>
                                <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                                <arg>-feature</arg>
                                <arg>-unchecked</arg>
                                <arg>-language:implicitConversions</arg>
                                <arg>-language:postfixOps</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skip.selenium.tests}</skip>
                    <parallel>none</parallel>
                    <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                    <disableXmlReport>false</disableXmlReport>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>runSeleniumTests</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Because you stated "I suppose (but it may not be true) that the logging activity takes a long time.", I suggest you actually measure the length of time that the logging activity consumes as compared with the time durations of the tests being processed. Then you'll quantitatively know if your premise is correct. However, if you are more concerned about the "huge table" than the processing durations, then you need to reduce the trivial logged outputs that take up space but provide no beneficial feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question was answer on [Gatling issues section](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/3465); this can be configured in `gatling.conf` file (in `test/resources`).

Instead of having:

```
gatling {
  data {
    writers = [console, file]
  }
}
```

You can have:

```
gatling {
  data {
    writers = [file]
  }
}
```

And now your console is clear.

Have a look at this if you need to know more about [gatling.conf file default values](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf).